# Drop down menu in PhP javascript html

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

Need your help in my application i have a php page (profile.php)  that give me this result:

```
Test1/Test
Test2/Test0
...
```

I want to put each line in this result in a selection bar like this one:

[image: result that i want]

but in fact the result was like this one :

[image: result that i have]

this is my code for m drop down menu:

```
<option value="0">please select an existing profile</option>
<?php
require('profile.php');
?>
```

code profile.php:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('/etc/init.d/dima --get-profilelist');
echo "<option value=\"" . $output ."\">".$output."</option>";
?>
```

Comment: you should add the code from profile.php, the problem is in there.

Comment: i edited the question @claudiu.brand

Answer (score 0):

Your result should looks like :

```
<option value="0">please select an existing profile</option>
<option value="1">Test1/Test</option>
<option value="2">Test2/Test0</option>
```

Yours is like that :

```
<option value="0">please select an existing profile</option>
<option value="0">Test1/Test Test2/Test0</option>
```

You have to enclose each result line in the tag  so that it can work as expected

Comment: i want that the drop down menu give the result of profile.php i cant do it manualy @Christophe Thiry

Answer (score 0):

$output is taking all the content in one line...you can use var_dump() to see how data is returned in $output and edit that... You need to use  for each value in the dropdown

Answer (score 0):

You should loop your `$output` and `echo` every option, Try This :

```
<?php
     $output = shell_exec('/etc/init.d/dima --get-profilelist');
     $optionsArray = explode(' ',$output);

     foreach(optionsArray as $option)
         echo "<option value='". $option."'>".$option."</option>";
?>
```

Hope this will help.